# Unable to handle date change when pausing until date

Tags: 2013, workflow, pause, date

I need a workflow to assign a task on `EndDate`. Initially I just tried this with a simple `Pause until date`, but this cannot handle date changes (the rest of the workflow is not actioned if someone changes the date we are waiting until).

I followed [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/pause-until-date-workflows-unable-to-handle-changing-dates) and ended up with this bit of workflow:

[image]

I can see that the end date really is being updated in my `WorkFlow History`, and the workflow is recognising the new date:

[image]

However, when the new `EndDate` arrives, I do not receive any emails and no tasks are assigned to me.

Why is this happening, and how can I handle a date change when pausing a workflow until some date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try logging the output of `Current Item:EndTime` to the workflow history list. It may be that the comparison still holds true that `Current Item:Endtime > Today` and so the loop is continuing.

You could wait and see if the task gets assigned once that comparison is false and you break out of the loop. Another option would be to set a boolean variable to test against instead of the date field. Then after the pause statement you could compare the `Current Item:EndTime <= Today` and set the boolean variable to false which would cause you to fall out of the loop.

[image]

Comment: So after outputting `Today` to the history, I can see that it only ever uses the time `00:00`, which is why it never works

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing. Are you assigning Today to a `Date/Time` variable and logging that variable to the history list?

Comment: I was able to resolve this with the changes in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by, making some arbitrary change to the current item at the beginning of the workflow, and then getting the modified date:

[image]

Then in the loop:

[image]

The call to `Today` was returning the current date, but it always had the time set to `00:00`