# Send email notification when a date is overdue in a list Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I have a problem that I can't find a proper solution. I have a list in SharePoint 2010 and one of the columns is Date Expiration. The thing is that I want to send an email to a user when this date is overdue.

The problems I'm facing are mainly:

- Send this notification even when the record is not updated
- I can't use today variable in a formula column

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In such case you have to create custom timer job and schedule it to run in every few moments.

Best ever article to learn [How to create timer job in SP 2010](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-tools/a-complete-guide-to-writing-timer-jobs-in-sharepoint-2010/)

**Using workflow:**

Create a workflow and use `while` activity and create your logic here.

For example see [this](https://brianscodingexamples.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/create-while-loop-within-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer-2010/) answer.

Configure the workflow and start it manually for the first time.

For more reference you can read answers to [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/145697/52649) post to get more clear ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for the suggestions but I'm a bit limited here. I'm only allowed to use out-of-the-box features (including workflows)...

Comment: Thanks Aakash. I tried this but when I type While Statement, designer says No results in red

Answer (score 0):

Write a timer job and check the condition with the Date Column, If that matches , send an email else no action