# Send email when date has arrived

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Got a list where a user needs to fill out a date field and when that date arrives confirmation email will be sent. All good I could do if date = today and it will send the email. How I could do that if it is date+2 from today. I read about pause until date but there is some kind of problems?

Comment: Its SharePoint On-Premises? 2013? There is no problem with the delay and wait until 2days. The workflow will be in state Running, internally saved to Workflow queue and after this OWSTimer will proceed it.

Comment: I am using SP 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simply Pause Until Action in SharePoint Workflow. There aren't any problems.

[image]

Comment: And it isn't working for me. I am not getting the email

Comment: What Date is inside this action? About it, if it'S today's date probably this email will come tomorrow. I dont know if this is pause until less than or pause until equal, so you must try it, but you need more days for testing, like set todays and tomorrow date and wait what to workflow will do.

Comment: I set date from the list. I am doing that but I heard that there is some kind of problems with it

Comment: which date? 16.1.2019 ? or different? Here is the same and its working, probably you have some misconfigurations.. http://sharepointdeveloperblog.blogspot.com/2016/10/pause-until-date-workflows-handle.html

Comment: You can also try this solution: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/pause-until-date-workflows-unable-to-handle-changing-dates

Comment: So Pause Until Date worked, but how could I workout two dates

Comment: How you mean that? If Date1 > Date2 : Use Date1 ?? Or how you mean that?

Comment: I have two dates. If date1 = today send confirmation else if date 2 = today send confirmation email. I think I just answered the question myself

Comment: Yes :) feel free to mark this as answer, thank you :)

Comment: mark it as answer please.